# Using a Dell TB16 on a computer without USB-C

Tags: usb, usb-3, dock, thunderbolt, usb-c

I own a dell TB16 dock. This dock is attached to my laptop via usb-c.
Now, I would occasionally like to attach an older laptop (older as in: from 2015, right before USB-C was by default integrated in business machines).

For this, I would need to be able to connect this dock through a usb-a 3 (or 3.1) port.
Does anyone know if this is possible at all? 
Would an adapter like https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01C43FUIW/ref=crt_ewc_title_gw_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=AMUN6OW4OKOC5 
work for that?

Comment: The TB series of docks *requires* Thunderbolt.

Comment: But would it provide certain functionality over "simple" USB3? Simple funcitonality of a USB3 dock?

Comment: Guess I'll probably just buy a D6000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start with a few basic explanations.

USB-C is a form factor for a connector. It does not require you to use USB on it, in fact, you may:

1. Have an USB-C connector running USB 1 only, with co capability for anything else. Sounds insane but according to spec this is legal.
2. Have an USB-C connector running USB 2 only. Not that old, and you can sell it as having USB-C to drive up sales.
3. Have an USB-C connector running USB 3 or 3.1 gen 1 (both same 5GB/sec).
4. Have an USB-C connector running USB 3 gen 2 (10Mbit/sec signaling)
5. Have an USB-C connector for thunderbolt 3, which is not USB. TB is like PCI-e lanes on a cable. It has cables for this, but it can also use alternate modes which **may** provide USB or Displayport.

The last point (5) makes things nicely and confusing. It looks like USB, it acts like USB, .... and it can do something completely different.

[image]

Now your Dell TB16 is a thunderbolt dock.  Finding a physical cable or plug which converts from the USB-C form to classic USB plugs is not going to help here.

You either need a dock with different requirements, or add TB to your laptop. The first is probably easiest.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, even so, an adapter of thunderbolt to USB-A 3.1 might exist, no? It would not just be a "form factor changer", but it would require some smarts, e.g., a chip to decode the thunderbolt signal and re-encode it as a USB 3.1or USB3.0 compatible signal. 

Of course, some restrictions on what content can be encoded into a usb3.1 compatible signal applies...

I mean: conceptually, my TB16 sends display informatoin, input info (keyboard and mouse), network info, ... All of which can be sent over USB-A as well...
Or do I miss something?

Comment: An adaptor from thudnerbolt to USB is trivial. That is just a fancy version of an PCI-e based USB card. The verses is much harder. You start with a relative slow interface (at most USB 3.1 gen 2, but probably gen 1) and you want to provide connectivity worth at least 3x that speed + alternate output lines (e.g. the graphics). Getting a second modern laptop is likely cheaper than the magic bullet which does that.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to use my dock by using a USB 3 to USB-c adapter.  The computer installed the correct drivers and functioned normally.  However, I was unable to charge the laptop and had to use a separate Power brick for power purposes.  Monitors, networking and USB devices connected through the dock all worked normally.

Machine in question was a Latitude 6540 and TB16.  The USB3 to USB-c adapter came with another Dell Dock, I believe it was a D6000.  I don't recall if the dock power button would power up the laptop, though.